# Getting UTF-8/19 code of emoticons entered by user

Tags: java, utf-8, utf-16, emoticons

I am building an android app, which includes a feature where a user can enter a string and emoticons (if he wants to). For example:

> Happy Halloween! :D :D :D

I want to get the UTF-8 code of the emoticons entered by the user, so in the background it looks like:

> Happy Halloween! U+1F601 U+1F601 U+1F601

Following is my code but it isn't working:

```
    class emoticons
   {
  public static void main(String[] args)
   {
    Scanner emo = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(emo.nextLine());   
    
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(<U\\+\\w+?>)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    List<String> matchList = new ArrayList<String>();

    while (matcher.find()) 
    {
        matchList.add(matcher.group());
    }

    for(int i=0;i<matchList.size();i++){
        System.out.println(matchList.get(i));
    }
```

So basically, i just want to get the UTF code of the emoticons pressed by the user.

Comment: If that is what your user enters, the string does not contain emoticon characters at all.

Comment: @Jongware: Why so? Is the system not going to consider it as a character or something? or will it just take only the string "happy halloweeen" and print it out?

Comment: Instead of this `U+1F601` a TextView will recognize this `\u1F601`. However, mind that not all Unicode characters are included in the standard system font. You have to resort to some emoticon library or specifc font for that.

Comment: Your example string contains plain ASCII characters only. Possibly you are *mentally* translating each of the last 3 sets of `:)` to a single Unicode character ``, or your software generally translates it *for* you and you are not aware of that (thus falsely led to *believe* that `:)` ≡ ``), or your example is really bad.